# How to pair two elements in a list in the output?

Tags: python, list

So I'm trying to make a code to calculate the difference between scores between two players in a quiz. There are first round scores and second round scores.

This is what I have so far:

```
import math

option = input ('How many players?: ')

playerlist = []
firstroundlist = []
secondroundlist = []

j = 0
while j < option:
    name = raw_input('Enter player\'s name: ')
    playerlist.append(name,)

    firstround = input ('Enter first round score: ')
    firstroundlist.append(firstround,)

    secondround = input('Enter second round score: ')
    secondroundlist.append(secondround,)

    j += 1

y=0
z=1
dis=[]
while z<len(playerlist):
    comparison = (firstroundlist[y]+secondroundlist[y])-(firstroundlist[z]+secondroundlist[z])
    print playerlist[y], '-', playerlist [z], 'is', comparison
    z+=1

z==0
y+=1
```

But, let's say I input the scores for four different players, the output for this code would be like this:

```
Player 1 - Player 2 is #scoredifference
Player 1 - Player 3 is #scoredifference
Player 1 - Player 4 is #scoredifference
```

The question is, how do I modify the code so that it would be something like this:

```
Player 1 - Player 2 is #scoredifference
Player 1 - Player 3 is #scoredifference
Player 1 - Player 4 is #scoredifference
Player 2 - Player 3 is #scoredifference
Player 2 - Player 4 is #scoredifference
Player 3 - Player 4 is #scoredifference
```

Comment: Side note: Don't use while-loops that way. Use `for j in range(option): …` instead (`range(1, len(playerlist))` for the second loop).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools
for y,z in itertools.combinations(range(len(playerlist)), 2):
    comparison = (firstroundlist[y]+secondroundlist[y])-(firstroundlist[z]+secondroundlist[z])
    print (playerlist[y] + '-' + playerlist[z] + 'is' + str(comparison))
```

Note that your data structure is not optimal. You should use [tuples](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) of player information, like this:

```
import itertools
playernum = int(raw_input('How many players?: '))
players = [(
    raw_input('Enter player\'s name: '),
    int(raw_input('Enter first round score: ')),
    int(raw_input('Enter second round score: ')),
) for i in range(playernum)]

for p,q in itertools.combinations(players, 2):
    comparison = (p[1]+p[2])-(q[1]+q[2])
    print (p[0] + '-' + q[0] + 'is' + str(comparison))
```

By the way, your current code contains a syntactic error. Instead of

```
name = raw_input('Enter player's name: ')
```

You want:

```
name = raw_input('Enter player\'s name: ')
```

Also, instead of `input()` (which executes arbitrary Python code!) you want `int(raw_input())`.

Comment: Thanks!
But I got this error: line 9, in <module>
    for p,q in itertools.combinations(players):
TypeError: Required argument 'r' (pos 2) not found

What does it mean?

Comment: Oops, sorry, my mistake - I left out the number of combinations I wanted. Updated the answer with `, 2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(playerlist)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(playerlist)):
        print "player %d - player %d is %d", (i, j, scoredifference[i,j])
```

should do the trick for you. Obviously replace `scoredifference` with the correct formula..

Comment: This will compare 3-3. Also, I think that a nested `range(len())` is really unpythonic.

Comment: @KurtSpindler Thank you! By the way, do you have any idea how can I print the average value of all the score differences?

Comment: I'd suggest putting them all the scores into an array, and then `sum(allScores)/len(allScores)` should do the trick!